# ngx-admin auth not posting when submitting login form

Tags: javascript, angular, nebular, ngx-admin

I am trying to use ngx-admin auth component but i cant seem to make it work.

I already installed nebular auth via npm and set up my app.module and app-routing.module

App.module

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CoreModule } from './@core/core.module';
import { ThemeModule } from './@theme/theme.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NbPasswordAuthStrategy, NbAuthModule } from '@nebular/auth';
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
import {
  NbChatModule,
  NbDatepickerModule,
  NbDialogModule,
  NbMenuModule,
  NbSidebarModule,
  NbToastrModule,
  NbWindowModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

     NbAuthModule.forRoot({
       strategies: [
         NbPasswordAuthStrategy.setup({
           name: 'email',
           baseEndpoint: environment.backend_url,
            login: {
              endpoint: 'login',
              method: 'post',
              redirect: {
               success: 'dashboard',
               failure: null, // stay on the same page
             },
            },
            register: {
              endpoint: '/auth/sign-up',
              method: 'post',
            },
            logout: {
              endpoint: '/auth/sign-out',
              method: 'post',
            },
            requestPass: {
              endpoint: '/auth/request-pass',
              method: 'post',
            },
            resetPass: {
              endpoint: '/auth/reset-pass',
              method: 'post',
            },
         }),
       ],
       forms: {
        login: {
          strategy: 'email',  // strategy id key.
          rememberMe: true,   // whether to show or not the `rememberMe` checkbox
          showMessages: {     // show/not show success/error messages
          success: true,
          error: true
          }
        }  
       }
     }), 

    ThemeModule.forRoot(),

    NbSidebarModule.forRoot(),
    NbMenuModule.forRoot(),
    NbDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    NbDialogModule.forRoot(),
    NbWindowModule.forRoot(),
    NbToastrModule.forRoot(),
    NbChatModule.forRoot({
      messageGoogleMapKey: 'AIzaSyA_wNuCzia92MAmdLRzmqitRGvCF7wCZPY',
    }),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

And app-routing.module

```
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  NbAuthComponent,
  NbLoginComponent,
  NbLogoutComponent,
  NbRegisterComponent,
  NbRequestPasswordComponent,
  NbResetPasswordComponent,
} from '@nebular/auth';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pages',
    loadChildren: () => import('app/pages/pages.module')
      .then(m => m.PagesModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: NbAuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: NbLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: NbLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: NbRegisterComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'logout',
        component: NbLogoutComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'request-password',
        component: NbRequestPasswordComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'reset-password',
        component: NbResetPasswordComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'auth/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: false,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

I am expecting a post request. When i tried to submit the login form and checked the network tab on my browser dev tools, there is nothing happening and no activity at all. But on the UI of the login page, it returns successful.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding my changes to core.module instead of app.module.